# If statement in VBA not working properly

Tags: vba, excel, if-statement

By some unknown reason my If statement is not working properly i tried to invert the signals if seek of any improvement , but none so far. Leaving some of the code bellow.

```
For i = 1 To last
    REFERENCIA = Application.ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Registos").Cells(i, 8)
    ENTRADAeSAIDA = Application.ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Registos").Cells(i, 12)
    CC = Application.ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Registos").Cells(i, 6)

    If REFERENCIA = registos.TextBox1 And registos.ComboBox1 = "SAÍDA" Then

         Worksheets("registos").Select
         ActiveSheet.ListObjects("Tabela1").Range.AutoFilter Field:=8, Criteria1:= _
         registos.TextBox1.Text             'Filtrar referência

         ActiveSheet.ListObjects("Tabela1").Range.AutoFilter Field:=6, Criteria1:= _
         registos.Label11.Caption           'Filtrar CC


         ActiveSheet.ListObjects("Tabela1").Range.AutoFilter Field:=12, Criteria1:= _
        "ENTRADA"                                'Filtrar Entrada

        'Somar quantidades de peças de Entrada
        xty100 = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("calculos").Range("A1")


    ''       Worksheets("registos").Select
        ActiveSheet.ListObjects("Tabela1").Range.AutoFilter Field:=12, Criteria1:= _
        "SAÍDA"                                            'Filtrar Saída
        xty101 = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("calculos").Range("A1")
    '        'Somar quantidade de peças de saída

        sumfinal = xty100 - xty101
        xytbx4 = Format(registos.TextBox4, "@")

     If xytbx4 < sumfinal And xytbx4 > 0 Then
    GoTo salto_2

    Else
    MsgBox "Não é possível movimentar mais que o stock atual!Stock " & sumfinal & ""
    GoTo fim
    End If
    End If
Next i
```

Comment: What does not working mean? What did you expect to see happen? Any errors? Which lines? What are the values and types of all those variables?

Comment: If xytbx4 < sumfinal And xytbx4 > 0 Then
GoTo salto_2

Comment: It was supposed to take me to salto_2 , but instead it's taking me to Else

Comment: And i always insert a number that's not even close to zero or sumfinal

Comment: And you definitely reach this point in the code when you step through?

Comment: Where is salto_2? It should be in the same sub.

Comment: When the user inserts the info and clicks commandbutton1 if it's true that the number inserted is greater than 0 and lower than sumfinal the info will be inserted to the worksheet if that doen'st verify it will go to fim: which will End Sub and do it all over

Comment: @JohnColeman Oops. Guilty!

Comment: with `xytbx4 = Format(registos.TextBox4, "@")` you write a string in `xytbx4` not a number. And then you look if that string is smaller than `sumfinal`? No good idea I think. Use `Option Explicit` and declare all your variable types correctly and compare numbers not strings.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You haven't DIM'ed your variables but from

```
 sumfinal = xty100 - xty101
```

It appears that you expect sumfinal to be numeric. But from

```
xytbx4 = Format(registos.TextBox4, "@")
```

xytbx4 is always a string (since that's what Format returns) with a numeric value of zero - so your IF will never be true

Comment: I have missed something. In my immediate window this `?100-format("12","@")` returns nicely `88`.

Comment: @Vityata and what does [vartype](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/language-reference-vba/articles/vartype-function) say? `?vartype(xytbx4)` ? I guess it says string. Of course there is an implicit cast of that string into a number if you start calculating that is why it works. But I would never rely on that.

Comment: @Pᴇʜ -probably. But I am missing the point there. The text is converted to a string and then the string is compared to a numeric. Although this is not a good practice at all, VBA can handle it quite nicely.

Comment: Thanks for the help , God bless you

Comment: @Vityata depending on your localization `CDbl(Format("12.6", "@"))` is different from `CDbl(Format("12,6", "@"))` and if the number you compare to is no integer it automatically casts into a double or something and you go crazy if a users input is not validated.

Comment: @Pᴇʜ - true, but somehow irrelevant. The answer is saying that numeric string is always parsed to a `0`. - **xytbx4 is always a string with a numeric value of zero** which is exactly what I am missing.

Comment: @Vityata well true, I totally agree with you in that point. It doesn't get zero but possibly a not expected value instead, which also might fail the `if` statement.

Comment: @Pᴇʜ - I see, the localization and the floating point can fail the condition indeed.

Comment: What do you think the result of this will be?  
?format(date(),"@")>format("1,120,000","@")

Comment: @HarassedDad for me it is `True` but it might depend on the date format in your operating system (mine is `yyyy-mm-dd`). I don't see what sense that makes comparing these 2 at all. `<` and `>` comparison of strings will drive you crazy soon or later, you never know what you really get. Therefore just compare dates or numbers instead.

Answer (score 0):

Check the 2 values of `xytbx4` and `sumfinal` before the `If` like this:

```
MsgBox "xytbx4: " & xtybx4
MsgBox "sumfinal: " & sumfinal

If xytbx4 < sumfinal And xytbx4 > 0 Then
```

This will return 2 `MsgBox` with the values of the variables in them.

Comment: xytbx4 returned "xytbx4:" and sumfinal returned "100"

Comment: @PedroGaspar - this means that `xytbx4` is not assigned correctly to a value. Try to declare it like `Dim xytbx4 as Long` and then see what happens further.